# Simultaneous downloads result in corrupted files

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm downloading sets of images in separated threads and saving them to the SD card. The problem is that when I run two or more downloading threads the saved images are corrupted. If just one thread is running the images are ok. I'm downloading it from the same domain but different url, e.g. www.test.com/set1/img1.jpg, www.test.com/set2/img1.jpg etc.

I'm saving them to different folders by the name of the set. I noticed that mostly larger images are corrupted (over 500 KB), smaller are usually ok, but not always.

Do you have any clue why the files get corrupted when multiple threads are running?

Here's a part of the code I'm using:

```
protected class DownloadTask extends DownloadRunnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        File bitmapFile = null;
        /** some more declarations and preparations are here */

        for (int pg=getDownloadedPages(); pg < numPages; ++pg) {

            for (char ch='a'; ch <= 'e'; ++ch) {
                /* check for pause */
                synchronized (pauseLock) {
                    while (paused && !aborted) {
                        try {
                            pauseLock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }                               
                    }
                }
                fileName = "page-" + df.format(pg) + "-" + ch;                          
                url = MainApp.getRestrictedUrl(MainApp.tstcode, urlFile + fileName+ ".jpg");                            
                is = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream());

                if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    bitmapFile = new File(pathToSave,  fileName + MagazinePage.FILE_EXT);
                    MainApp.encryptToFile(bitmapFile, is);
                    dwnlSize += bitmapFile.length();
                }
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void encryptToFile(File file, InputStream is) throws IOException {        
    BufferedOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            } else {
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }
            file.createNewFile();
            os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            IkioskContentProvider.getInstance().encrypt(is, os);
        } finally {
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

DownloadRunnable is custom abstract class implementing Runnable. And I'm using it in thread the regular way:

```
protected void downloadIssuePages() {
    dwnlTask = new DownloadTask();
    new Thread(dwnlTask).start();
}
```

I'm calling downloadIssuePages() on two different objects to download two sets for example.

Using SDK version 11 (Android 3.0), device Acer Iconia Tab A500 with Android 3.1

Comment: I have a theory why it might be happening, when you use threads and they can sometimes overrite each others data, in other words they might be writing to the same file name or same memory location or something like that, usually doing things like this I would advise using locks but I don't know about locks for what you are doing and I am still new to mobile dev

Comment: Thanks for a tip, I came to the same conclusion. But the thing is that these threads are writing to different files so they should not collide. Apparently there're some collisions in the data flow of the streams or what. I used lock now when writing to the file and looks like it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to disable writing for the second thread, only the first thread was saving files to find out if there's a problem in reading from the stream or writing. Apparently writing was the problem as data was correct in this case.

So I decided to use lock around writing to the file and looks like it's working fine:

```
synchronized (MainApp.fileWritingLockObj) {
    while (MainApp.fileWritingLocked) {
        try {
            MainApp.fileWritingLockObj.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }                               
    }
    MainApp.fileWritingLocked = true;                           
    if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        bitmapFile = new File(pathToSave,  fileName + MagazinePage.FILE_EXT);
        MainApp.encryptToFile(bitmapFile, is);
        dwnlSize += bitmapFile.length();
    }
    is.close();
    MainApp.fileWritingLocked = false;
    MainApp.fileWritingLockObj.notifyAll();
}
```